# Breeze .NET Server code throws Int32Converter exception

Tags: breeze

I started seeing the following error after I made some code changes to my JavaScript client code. I have seen others report it too but have not seen anybody able to narrow down the conditions.

```
Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Int64.
```

After much digging into the problem, it appears to be a bug in the Breeze .NET server code. Part of the exception stack trace here shows where the error originates from:

```
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.ConvertValue(Object val, Type toType) in EFContextProvider.cs:line 603
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.SetPropertyValue(Object entity, String propertyName, Object value) in EFContextProvider.cs:line 573
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.<>c__DisplayClass10.<RestoreOriginal>b__f(KeyValuePair`2 kvp) in EFContextProvider.cs:line 468
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.RestoreOriginal(EntityInfo entityInfo) in EFContextProvider.cs:line 466
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.<ProcessAllDeleted>b__9(EFEntityInfo entityInfo) in EFContextProvider.cs:line 337
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.ProcessAllDeleted(List`1 deletedEntities) in EFContextProvider.cs:line 334
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.SaveChangesCore(SaveWorkState saveWorkState) in EFContextProvider.cs:line 219
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.ContextProvider.OpenAndSave(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
  at Breeze.ContextProvider.ContextProvider.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle, TransactionSettings transactionSettings)
```

What is happening is that `EFContextProvider<>.ConvertValue()` is called with a `long` as first parameter and the second parameter is the `Type` for `int?`. From there the retrieved `TypeConverter` fails to convert it and throws the above exception.

I was able to reproduce the error by downloading DocCode and writing the following test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task RemovingNavigationProperty()
    {
        var entityManager = await TestFns.NewEm(_northwindServiceName);

        var employee = new Employee()
        {
            FirstName = "First",
            LastName = "Employee"
        };
        entityManager.AddEntity(employee);


        var manager = new Employee()
        {
            FirstName = "First",
            LastName = "Manager"
        };
        entityManager.AddEntity(manager);
        employee.Manager = manager;

        try
        {
            var saveResult = await entityManager.SaveChanges();

            // Now reverse everything
            manager.EntityAspect.Delete();
            employee.Manager = null;

            employee.EntityAspect.Delete();

            saveResult = await entityManager.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var message = string.Format("Save should have succeeded;  Received {0}: {1}",
                                        e.GetType().Name, e.Message);
            Assert.Fail(message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice catch.  As of 6/16/2014, this has been fixed in the breeze.server.net GitHub repo and will also be part of the next full breezeJs release, hopefully out later this week. I will post back here when it goes out in the new nuget packages.